# Is every method in Java overridable

Tags: java, oop

Is every method in Java overridable? I know that in C# methods defined as virtual can be overriden, how was this implemented in Java?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not every method is overridable: you cannot override methods that are `final`, `private` and `static`.

below is a small sample of what this means in practice:

```
class Base {
    public final void fun1() {
    }

    private void fun2() {
        System.out.println("Base::fun2");
    }

    public void fun2Call() {
        fun2();
    }        
}

class Rextester extends Base
{  
    /*
    @Override
    public void fun1() { // compile error, because Base::fun1 is final
    } 
    */

    // if @Override is uncommented, it will protect you from overriding private methods
    //  otherwise you will not get any compile time error.
    //@Override 
    private void fun2() {
        System.out.println("Rextester::fun2");
    }    

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Base b = new Rextester();
        b.fun2Call(); // will output Base::fun2,
                      // if you change private to protected or public 
                      // then you will see Rextester::fun2 in output
    }
}
```

I think `static` method overriding is the same case as `private` method overriding, at least you will get similar behaviour. Of course changing `static` method to `public` or `protected` will still not allow you to override it.

Comment: So this is correct, but consider adding that the concrete answer to OP's question is NO, not every method is overrideable.  Also, I don't think java has the distinction that C# makes with "virtual methods"

Comment: When you think about it, in C# you can't make the method virtual and static that doesn't make much sense. And you can't declare virtual methods to bi private. So there might not be much difference between this.

Comment: @Michael27, why not. A static method can't be inherited (cause it's implicitely sealed) and hence can't be overriden at all. Similarly, private methods are. the whole point for being `overriden` is to override it in derived class. if it's somehow not available to derived type then there is no point of making it virtual/overridable.

Answer (score 4):

final, static and private methods are not overridable. All the rest are.

> **final** prevents overriding because, well, this is what it was meant for.
>
> **static** means to belong to the *Class* and not the instance.
>
> **private** - no visibility, no overriding.

Also, JIT is happier when it sees methods as non-overridable, since it means monomorphic dispatch of the method, which means it is a *perfect candidate* for inlining the method, as there is no other instance that can override this one. This might be of no importance to you right now, but it speeds up the method pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

No, not all are. Method(s) marked with either of `final`, `private` ,`static` modifiers are not overridable at all.

Comment: @Joffrey, yes but multiple people can give same answer; which is indeed valid unless it's a copy or wrong.

Comment: You said it yourself: *unless it's a copy*. What's the point in adding the same answer? The point of this forum is to build a big dictionary of questions/answers. Providing 3 times the same answer does not serve any purpose, but adds more confusion for future readers, or at least make them scroll, which is annoying ^^